# ANTLR parser node type + Tree Adopter?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

I have developed small ANTLR grammar. which contains three files.

- GLexer.g : lexer
- GParser.g : parser of tpye AST
- GWalker.g : tree parser

Also I have custom tree node GTree (extends CommonTree) and tree adopterGAdaptor ( extends CommonTreeAdaptor ). See sample code below.

**lexer : GLexer.g**

```
lexer grammar GLexer;
..
some lexer rule
..
```

**Parser GParser.g **

```
parser grammar GParser;
options {
    output          = AST;
    tokenVocab      = GLexer;
}
statement 
  : 
     rule* 
       -> ^(STATEMENTS rules* )
  ;
```

**Tree Grammar : GWalker.g**

```
tree grammar GWalker;
options {
  tokenVocab      = GParser;
  ASTLabelType    = GTree;
}
statement returns [String node]
  : 
     ^(STATEMENTS rules* )
  ;
```

**Tree node**

```
public class GTree extends CommonTree {
    public String text;
    public HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    public GTree(Token t) {
        super(t);
        text = (t != null ? t.getText() : "[]");
    }
}
```

**Tree Adopter**

```
public class GTreeAdaptor extends CommonTreeAdaptor {
    public GTree create(Token payload) {
        GTree c = new GTree(payload);
        return c;
    }
}
```

**ANTLR handler**

```
try {
    //lexer splits input into tokens
    ANTLRStringStream input = new ANTLRStringStream("input String");
    TokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream( new GLexer( input ) );

    //parser generates abstract syntax tree
    GParser parser = new GParser(tokens);
    // Initiate Custom Adopter and set in parser
    TreeAdaptor adaptor = new GTreeAdaptor();
    parser.setTreeAdaptor(adaptor);
    GParser.statement_return st = parser.statement();

    CommonTreeNodeStream gTreeNodeStream = new CommonTreeNodeStream(
            st.getTree());

    GWalker gwalker = new GWalker(gTreeNodeStream);
    String returnValue = gwalker.statement();
    // print returnValue
} catch (RecognitionException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Recognition exception is never thrown, only declared.");
}
```

When I run handle code above , it is giving casting exception. I know why this casting exception when all nodes in generated AST should be of type **GTree** as my custom tree adopter GTreeAdaptor will create only tree node of type GTree.

Help me understandinmg this and getting it resoved.

**Casting exception**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.antlr.runtime.tree.CommonTree cannot be cast to driver.antlr.model.GTree       
at driver.antlr.lexerparser.GWalker.statement(GWalker.java:119)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolved by adding method **dupNode()** in class **GTreeAdaptor**

**Link :**
https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2687038

**Changed Adopter Definition :**

```
public class GTreeAdaptor extends CommonTreeAdaptor {
   public GTree create(Token payload) {
       GTree c = new GTree(payload);
       return c;
   }
   public Object dupNode(Object t) {
       if ( t==null ) return null;
       return create(((GTree )t).token);
   }
}
```